# Mysql count columns of users, and group by modified date

Tags: mysql, select, count

There are 2 columns that I want data from. Basically I want to see new signups per day. Go easy on me, my first day with mysql (or any DB for that matter)

So far I have this

```
mysql> select created, count(id) from user group by created;
+---------------------+-----------+
| created             | count(id) |
+---------------------+-----------+
| 2009-05-27 00:58:56 |         1 | 
| 2009-05-27 01:27:30 |         1 | 
| 2009-05-27 02:35:37 |         1 | 
| 2009-05-27 02:58:56 |         1 | 
| 2009-05-27 03:36:03 |         1 | 
| 2009-05-27 03:38:03 |         1 | 
| 2009-05-27 03:48:16 |         1 | 
| 2009-05-27 03:51:37 |         1 |
```

The output I would like is

```
+---------------------+----------------------+
| created             | user                 |
+---------------------+----------------------+
| 2009-05-27          | 10                   |
| 2009-05-28          | 13                   | 
| 2009-05-29          | 19                   |
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
select DATE(created), count(id) from user group by DATE(created);
```

Comment: +1 for quick and correct answer. You could also add column aliases to make it easier to access the result from the query in the language of choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE(created) as date, count(1) as nrRegistered
FROM user
GROUP BY date
```

Note: By counting 1 instead of id we avoid a lookup in the table and enable an index-only query

Comment: That's assuming the created field is indexed.

Comment: Yes it is. It also assumes that MySQL isn't clever enough to use the id (which is most probably a primary key) that is appended to the index when doing count(id). So I have to admit that it's a pretty loose note. But I didn't say that my query forces an index-only join, just that it makes it possible. I'd suggest using an EXPLAIN [...] on the query to make sure.

Comment: clarification: The primary key is appended if the storage engine is InnoDB, not MyISAM.